# Kuzzle JS SDK how to use the S3 Plugin

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, kuzzle

I'm looking for help in using the Kuzzle JS SDK (node JS)

Websocket protocol to upload a file to the S3 Plugin. I see the HTTP JS example here https://github.com/kuzzleio/kuzzle-plugin-s3/blob/master/test/s3-upload-test.html

But I'm looking for a way to use the WebSocket protocol.

Also - im going to want to use the S3 plugin for listing and validating via Node JS.

Im not finding the [kuzzle-plugin-s3](https://github.com/kuzzleio/kuzzle-plugin-s3) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the kuzzle-plugin-s3 documention [here](https://docs.kuzzle.io/official-plugins/s3/2/essentials/installation/)

Also in the example you provided use the websocket protocol, see [this line](https://github.com/kuzzleio/kuzzle-plugin-s3/blob/aa85898d6ced97027356658504c7a9aea4edc907/test/s3-upload-test.html#L23)

The [query method](https://github.com/kuzzleio/kuzzle-plugin-s3/blob/aa85898d6ced97027356658504c7a9aea4edc907/test/s3-upload-test.html#L32) of the JS SDK is used to call the kuzzle-plugin-s3 API